# What constitutes active participation in the public beta?

Tags: support

What did you have to do to get the `beta` badge? I thought I was fairly active, albeit only for the last couple of days of the private beta (holiday got in the way)... I'm just curious...

I got the beta badge for the math site, and I don't think I was any less active here, which is why I ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I vaguely remember that when committing on area51 one commits to asking or answering three questions in the private beta. I think that is is minimum for the badge.

Comment: I thought that was the required commitment for the entire beta period (public and private)... maybe I misread it.

Comment: Now it says 10 for the entire period. Maybe my memory is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The requirements are pretty minimal: [I got one for 2 questions, 3 answers, and 1 vote on gadgets](http://gadgets.stackexchange.com/users/96/larry-wang). However, the process that hands out beta badges is run manually, so you will not see it appear immediately.